# Error with MessageBox.Show in C#

Tags: c#, numbers, addition

Consider this code:

```
int total = 0;
using(var inFile = new StreamReader("text.txt"))
{
    string inValue = "";
    while ((inValue = inFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if(Int32.TryParse(inValue, out number))
        {
             total += number;
             Console.WriteLine("{0}", number);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - not a number", inValue);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("The sum is  {0}", total);
```

If I do `MessageBox.Show("{0}", number);`, it gives me an error. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is this a terminal app? That might explain things.

Comment: WHAT ERROR? You love screaming - but you also love giving zero relevant information. Not a smart combo. If you get an error, tell us what error. Oh, and maybe read up on the method you call...

Answer (score 1):

It definitely looks like you are writing a console application and then Messagebox is out of the question. But if you are in fact writing a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application, here is the answer:

Messagebox doesn't have a "built-in" formatter, like `Console.WriteLine`. If you want to format the string you must use `String.Format`:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}", number));
```

Alternatively:

```
MessageBox.Show(number.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

[The MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/20stz12s(v=vs.110).aspx) states pretty clearly, that `MessageBox.Show` does take two strings. But those two are not format and parameter, but text and caption. If you want to format your text, use string.Format to format a string *before* calling the method. You may also use one of the other overloads, but whichever you use, you need to do your own formatting.

> **Namespace:**  System.Windows.Forms
>
> **Assembly:**  System.Windows.Forms (in System.Windows.Forms.dll)

This means you need this namespace and you need the dll in your references. Both does not happen by default in a Console Application.

Answer (score 0):

`MessageBox` will not work in Console Applications.

Comment: why not?  better if you explained.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the line

```
    MessageBox.Show("{0}", number);
```

You can not call MessageBox.show() in the way you call Console.writeline(). The second parameter in MessageBox.show is MessageBox title. Try writing

```
MessageBox.Show(number)
```

or

```
MessageBox.Show("The sum is "+number);
```